# firebase is not working and showing error after install NPM and NVM

Tags: node.js, firebase, node-modules

after installing many version of npm finally fix the node issue by installing NVM but after that firebase shows the below error

> firebase : The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - firebase init
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI (rather than the SDK itself) is installed using:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

It can also be installed using a binary on Linux/Bash-enabled systems using `curl -sL firebase.tools | bash` (see/review https://firebase.tools for further details).